# Getting 409 Conflict responses on my Laravel endpoints using inertiajs/react

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I'm relatively new to using InertiaJS and currently facing an issue with my Laravel endpoints returning a 409 Conflict error and triggering a page refresh. I have a function that calls a Laravel endpoint on a button click, and here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
export default function CompanyInformation({ auth }) {
    const { errors, data } = usePage().props;

    const handleButtonClick = async (value) => {
        await Inertia.get("/company-information/profile", {
            symbol: value,
        });
    };

    return (
// ... some parts of the component ...
                            {data && (
                                <CompanyProfile
                                    details={data.company_profile}
                                />
                            )}
// ... rest of the component ...
    );
}
```

The corresponding controller function in Laravel looks like this:

```
public function getCompanyInformation(Request $request)
    {
        try {
        // ... processing ...
            $response = [
                'company_profile' => $result
            ];

            return Inertia::render('CompanyInformation', ['data' => $response]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return Inertia::render('CompanyInformation', ['errors' => [
                'exception' => $e->getMessage()
            ]]);
        }
    }
```

The behavior I'm observing is that the browser is forced to reload before displaying the correctly rendered page. I expected InertiaJS to render the CompanyProfile component without a page reload, similar to the behavior with api calls using axios and setting states.

I tried using Inertia.replace() to no avail. I also tried modifying `HandleIntertiaRequests.php` as I've read it had to do something with asset versions not being up to date(?) but it didn't also work

```
    public function version(Request $request): string|null
    {
        // return parent::version($request);
        return '';
    }
```

I'm uncertain if this is normal behavior with InertiaJS or if there's a potential issue. Any insights or guidance on this matter would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/what-is-a-409-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it?page=1&replyId=631626 ?